# Default Random String Django Model (python 2.7)

Tags: python, django

I have run into this issue a few times and have just given up on it and used a UUID, but I have a case where I need to make this work.

Basically I have a model with a CharField that's 6 characters in length and needs to be a random string.  I'm currently trying to accomplish this with:

```
referral_id = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=util.unique_referral_id, unique=True)
```

In util.py here is the code:

```
def unique_referral_id():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6))
```

However, everytime I try to migrate this code, unique_referral_id keeps returning the same string.  It is important that every referral_id is unique, and I understand my current function will not do that, but currently I am just praying to the RNG gods.  I'm more interested in learning WHY this function isn't returning a unique value every time.

Thanks!

Comment: Think you'll need to manually add a custom function into your migration to do this - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields

Comment: What do you mean with "everytime I try to migrate this code"?